# Postgres - SQL state: 22P02

Tags: sql, postgresql

En la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT t1.codigo
FROM tabla1 AS t1
INNER JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.codigo = t2.codigo
WHERE CASE WHEN POSITION( '-' IN t1.codigo ) = 0
          THEN CAST((t1.codigo) AS INTEGER)
          ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING( t1.codigo, 0, POSITION( '-' IN t1.codigo ) ) AS INTEGER)
      END
>
      CASE WHEN POSITION( '-' IN '1378' ) = 0 THEN
                CAST((SELECT codigo FROM tabla WHERE codigo = '1378') AS INTEGER)
           ELSE
                CAST(SUBSTRING( '1378', 0, POSITION( '-' IN '1378' ) ) AS INTEGER)
           END 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN POSITION( '-' IN t1.codigo ) = 0
          THEN CAST((t1.codigo) AS INTEGER)
          ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING( t1.codigo, 0, POSITION( '-' IN t1.codigo ) ) AS INTEGER)
      END
ASC LIMIT 1
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

> *ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «» SQL state: 22P02*

Lo que quiero conseguir en esta consulta es que me muestre el número siguiente, si existe, al que que paso por variable(en este ejemplo 1378). De hecho lo que hace es convertir un campo de texto a un integer quitando el guión en caso de que lo tenga.

Ejemplo número: 1183 o 110-1118

Utilizo PostgreSQL como base de datos y los campos código son Character Varying de 200 caracteres.

Lo curioso del tema es que me sucede en uno de los esquemas que tengo en la base de datos ya que en otro esquema, el original no me da este error, son tablas clonadas.

Así que estoy muy confuso con el tema.

He probado sin el `where` y funciona, el problema está ahí pero no logro encontrarlo.

Podéis ayudarme?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Seguro que esto funciona: `WHERE CASE WHEN....`?  el `WHERE no debería comparar algún valor con algo?

Comment: @A.Cedano si funciona esta consulta te lo aseguro. El WHERE compara dos resultados de cada CASE, si uno es mayor(>) que el otro